# How to convert a float value to byte array in swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, byte

The code which I am using for getting data in bytes, but I am not getting correct byte data for float value

```
let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt32)

// create array of appropriate length:
var array = [UInt32](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

// copy bytes into array
data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt32))

print(array)
```

Comment: What exactly is the input data and what the expected result? The title says "convert a float value to byte array" and your code does "NSData to UInt32 array", so your problem is not clear to me :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, if I am having float value, I want to convert that float value in bytes. so let me know what should I  do for that?

Comment: Example please? Do you want the IEEE 754 representation or the `integer.fraction` representation in binary?

Comment: Suppose for e.g float value is 40.0 , I want this float value to be converted in NSData, and then the  reverse case also nsdata to float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Float` to `NSData`:

```
var float1 : Float = 40.0
let data = NSData(bytes: &float1, length: sizeofValue(float1))
print(data) // <00002042>
```

... and back to `Float`:

```
var float2 : Float = 0
data.getBytes(&float2, length: sizeofValue(float2))
print(float2) // 40.0
```

(The same would work for other "simple" types like `Double`,
`Int`, ...)

**Update for Swift 3,** using the new `Data` type:

```
var float1 : Float = 40.0
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &float1, count: 1))
print(data as NSData) // <00002042>

let float2 = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as Float
print(float2) // 40.0
```

(See also [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data.))

**Update for Swift 4** and later:

```
var float1 : Float = 40.0
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &float1, count: 1))

let float2 = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float.self) } 
print(float2) // 40.0
```

*Remark:* `load(as:)` requires the data to be properly aligned, for `Float` that would be on a 4 byte boundary. See e.g. [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data) for other solutions which work for arbitrarily aligned data.

Comment: `Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))` whats different in this data to float conversion as it's outputting different value actually I need reverse of this means Float to Data but above code in your answer is not converting as expected, please help

Comment: Note that the Swift 3 version shown here now generates a warning with Swift 5: `Initialization of 'UnsafeBufferPointer<Self>' results in a dangling buffer pointer`

Comment: @featherless: I get a different warning “'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated” and I have updated the code. It should now compile without warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the update Martin. The new code does work + compile but it looks like it doesn't handle misaligned data. See https://github.com/jverkoey/BinaryCodable/pull/58/files for the fix I put in place based on swift-nio's number conversion implementation: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/06649bb8c704a042fc07f2013ae429e2d646e7bb/Sources/NIO/ByteBuffer-int.swift#L50-L61

Comment: @featherless: That is correct, `load(as:)` requires the data to be properly aligned. (See also https://forums.swift.org/t/built-in-unaligned-loads/19664 in the Swift Forum.) For arbitrarily aligned data I wrote something here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415, that is essentially the same approach as in your link.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5** Solution

From `Float` to `[UInt8]`

```
extension Float {
   var bytes: [UInt8] {
       withUnsafeBytes(of: self, Array.init)
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
let number: Float = 36.5
let bytes = number.bytes
```

From `[UInt8]` to `Float`

```
bytes.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: Float.self)
}
```

To convert to Data, simply cast the array of bytes to `Data`

```
let data = Data(bytes)
```